# WCF maxReceivedMessageSize not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service that has these configuration settings.  When I call it from a client application I still hit the dreaded, "Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'"  What's wrong with my configuration below?

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeBuffer" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="TestWcfService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeBuffer" name="ServiceEndPoint"
      contract="TestWcfService.IService1">
      <identity>
       <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
   </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you increased the maxItemsInObjectGraph quota beyond its default value on both the sending (serializing) and receiving (deserializing) sides? It applies both when reading and writing data.

Comment: Does the same config apply for your client, too?? You're only showing the server-side config - both sides need to have the new settings for it to work.

Comment: Do I have to basically copy everything between the config files then, Myles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I increased it on the client side to match.  And it still hits that limit.  My concern is that when it pulls the service reference back, it still sees 65536 as the default size so it never recognizes the larger amount.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my client side code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ServiceEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:61423/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="ServiceEndPoint" contract="LucasImport.IService1"
                name="ServiceEndPoint">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```